# Overflow: scroll causing image to be cut off

Tags: css, image, scroll, overflow

I have an image inside a scrollable div and it is getting cut off by about 50% I am guessing. I can only see the bottom 50%.

Here is the relevant css:

```
.imgContainer{
  height:auto;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  overflow:auto;
}

.img{
  width: auto;
  max-width:100vw;
  height:auto;
}
```

Here's a link to a deployed version on heroku (you may have to click "skip" a few times to get an image and clicking an image lets you see the full version). https://weratestatists-bot.herokuapp.com

Also if anyone can figure out why my favicon isn't working I'd much appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
.post, .titleCont {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

to

```
.post, .titleCont {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

Also your favicon is broken in some browsers because you put 2 slashes in the URL

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//favicon.ico?v=2">
```

should be

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do center crop image so that each center part of image is shown amd it will also make sure that your image is neither pixelated nor stretched

```
    Img {
Object-fit: cover;
Object-position: center;
}
```